# Access template reference inside a template element

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm using a library that expects me to specify body of a directive as a child of `template` element

```
<template customDirective>
   <custom-element #lookup></custom-element>
</template>
```

Is there a way to access `custom-element#lookup` inside my component.

For eg.,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <template customDirective>
       <custom-element #lookup></custom-element>
    </template>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {
  @ViewChild('lookup') viewChildRef;
  @ContentChild('lookup') contentChildRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
     console.log(this.viewChildRef); // <-- undefined
     console.log(this.contentChildRef); // <-- undefined
  }
}
```

I'm getting `undefined` in both cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot get reference to component inside template until you don't create embedded view.

Try using setter like:

```
@ViewChild('lookup') 
set lookUp(ref: any) {
  console.log(ref);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vDuvY4s7phxoYyubOSyd?p=preview)**

Comment: Looks like it is set right before ngAfterViewInit() is called. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look on `lookedUpCustomElemRef` inside `ngAfterViewInit` callback.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html