# How to access local variable wrapped inside ng-bootstrap template in our component in Angular js 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngBootstrap with angular 2 and using tabset like below

```
<ngb-tabset  class="cab-navbar-active active">
    <ngb-tab>
        <template ngbTabTitle>
            <div>SOME
                <span class="badge badge-warning" style="margin-left: 10px;">{{someList?.length}}</span>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template ngbTabContent>
            <p-dataTable #pDataTable [value]="someList" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" sortMode="multiple" emptyMessage=""> 
                <p-column *ngFor="let col of cCols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header | uppercase" [sortable]="true" [style]="col.style">                        
                </p-column>
            </p-dataTable>
        </template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Well, If you see I have defined local template variable named as **#pDataTable**
and we can access using **@ViewChild** but for me its coming as undefined.

But when I define **p-dataTable** outside **ngb-tabset** it works, I am able to access it.

I don't understand whats the problem here, I tried both **@ViewChild** and **@ConentChildern** but no luck.

Kindly let me know, proper way to access local variable wrapped inside ng-bootstrap tabset template in our defined component.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534524/access-template-reference-inside-a-template-element

Comment: Yes, it is working properly as when tab is activated and it is setting value of  ViewChild not initially. My bad I didn't looked properly.