# Cannot read property 'contactDetails' of undefined?

Tags: angular

I have this contactdetail model where i have this:

```
export class Contact{
    public displayname:string;
    constructor(){}
}
```

In my component contactdetail.component.ts i have this:

```
     export class ContactDetail implements OnInit {

    contactDetails: Contact = new Contact();
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

}
```

In my contactdetail.template.html i have this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control-full" placeholder="-" [(ngModel)]="contactDetails.displayname" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Now i have another component preview where i have this:

```
 @ViewChild( ContactDetail ) contactDetailForm: ContactDetail;
```

But i do this i get an error:

```
this.contactDetailForm.contactDetails.displayname = contact.displayname;
```

Any suggestion why is that?

This is where im using contactdetail component:

```
 <z-card-basic title="Details" *ngIf="showSubTab('Contact')"  (pinButtonClicked)="pinTab($event)" [buttons]="customTabButtons" block="block-tab-grid" header="block-header-grey" body="no-padding" >
                    <contact-detail></contact-detail>
                </z-card-basic>
```

Comment: Try it inside `ngAfterViewInit` hook

Comment: im getting same error

Comment: Can you create plunker? I don't see template where you are using `ContactDetail` component

Comment: @None Are you sure that component `ContactDetail` is exported in module file?

Comment: can you show the html side of the component where you are doing `viewchild` ?

Comment: i updated my question..problem is in ngIf ..when i remove it then works...but i need ngIf

Comment: and `showSubTab` takes what?

Comment: showSubTab(tab) {
        return this.openedSubTab === tab  || this.isPinned(tab);
    }

It only checks if tab is pinned or its default tab

Comment: you are sending a string literal as a param.. not sure if thats what you intended..

Comment: Yes i want that and that is working...problem is that i can not initialize values for contactdetail because of ngIf

Comment: where are you setting `this.contactDetailForm.contactDetails.displayname = contact.displayname;` ngOnInit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534524/access-template-reference-inside-a-template-element