# Angular - reuse component for display & modify causes @input problems?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a `user` component which displays a user info.

```
 <my-user [person]="person1" (onEdit)="showEdit($event)"></my-user>
```

As you can see , i'm already sending the value to display via `@Input()`.

[image]

Now I want to let a user edit this info via another `user` component.

So when a user clicks `edit` , I emit (via EventEmitter) the object up to the parent and in the parent I conditionally display the edit section ( *with the same values*) :

This is the parent component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <div> Person details : <br>

     <my-user [person]="person1" (onEdit)="showEdit($event)"></my-user>

    <ng-template [ngIf]="isEditing" >      <----- conditional edit section
      Edit Section:
      <my-user  #someElement  ></my-user>
    </ng-template>

    </div>
  `,
})
```

But the problem is that `<my-user>` has an `@input` and I don't pass that Input becuase it's conditionally displayed.
And hence the error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

And I think it comes from the inner component trying to use the @Input :

```
 ID: <input [(ngModel)]="person.id" type='text'   /><br>
```

**Question**

*I know that I can/should create another component for edit OR use a Subject to subscribe to an edit event   - but still :*
How can I conditionally display the same component and fill(!) the needed-to-be-modified  values ?

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CIZpw8zyEWKBqY2Sio0S?p=preview)

Comment: `@Input()  person:Person = {};` or safe navigation operator `person?.id`?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/voeHqFHXDvArNN4KKWtw?p=preview or clone object if you want to have save/cancel button https://plnkr.co/edit/XqjKgc4qcGZ7ret1uxjq?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thank you . BTW why does `@ViewChild('someElement') child` is `undefined` where I explicitly set  `#someElement` in the component ? I was hoping to fill values via that variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534524/access-template-reference-inside-a-template-element This https://plnkr.co/edit/ALU45xgP3o1vcJckKwsz?p=preview will also work

Comment: @Royi the problem there is that it's inside an `*ngIf`, which means that it is not created at the moment you call the function, because `isEditing` is still `false` (according to the current change detection cycle). You should start a new change detection cycle, and it will be visible then

Comment: @PierreDuc is right

Comment: Thank you both for your help. BTW @yuruzi - your last plnk also answered a future question of mine : when I pass an object to the edit zone - I don't want to reflect the online input changes in the original component ( in other words , a change in the bottom component should not be visible online with the first component) and you solved it with Object.assign. My ugly trick was to `JSON.stringify` the emitted value and then JSON.parse them in the edit zone. But your solution via Object.assign is better. tnx

Comment: @PierreDuc Thanks for clarification. indeed [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: @yurzui Regarding your first comment here , did you mean `<input [(ngModel)]="person?.id" type='text'   />` because I get an error if I do that.

Comment: `[ngModel]="person?.id" (ngModelChange)="person && person.id = $event"` https://plnkr.co/edit/AwC39BAfHnT0N5mT9uP0?p=preview Or just wrap with `*ngIf`

Comment: @yurzui Thanks but now ( after`(ngModelChange)="person && person.id = $event"`). when I click `edit` I get errors.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/AwC39BAfHnT0N5mT9uP0?p=preview We can't use `?` inside `ngModelChange`. Sorry i mixed it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a `Person` instance during creation of the component:

```
export class User {

  @Input()  person:Person = new Person();

  constructor() {}
}
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6JgsHiGrHjSRtMYaGGeB?p=preview)

Comment: A foolish mistake of myne.