# Why am I getting an undefined error when using ngIf and ViewChild together

Tags: html, angular

Angular CLI6

In my component, I have:

```
@ViewChild('necRiskAnalysisDialog')
private necRiskAnalysisDialog;
```

at some point I make a call to

```
this.necRiskAnalysisDialog.set(...
```

In my html, I have

```
<div>
<div *ngIf="someCondition">
    <nec-risk-analysis #necRiskAnalysisDialog></nec-risk-analysis>
</div>
</div>
```

I get a undefined for `necRiskAnalysisDialog`  in the line where I say `this.necRiskAnalysisDialog.set`

How do I get around this?

Comment: Does this happen with `someCondition` is false? If so it might be worth checking the value of `someCondition` before trying to set a value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534524/access-template-reference-inside-a-template-element/42540586#42540586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, you are accessing viewChild() property inside ngAfterViewInit() method.

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzznko

You can play with 'testcond' property and refer console.log().